# Ways to order elements in a set?

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-set-theory

Assume I have a set $S=\{1,\ldots,n\}$ that is not necessarily indexed. Since sets are inherently unordered, I would like to make a sequence $a=(a_1,\ldots,a_n)$ of the elements in $S$ such that $a_1<\cdots<a_n$.

I guess I need to map the values somehow, but how to do it? Note that I write sequence here rather than tuple since all the elements in $S$ are integers, in case it makes any difference. Maybe there are other, better ways than the one proposed above.

Comment: This doesn't really make sense to me. Can you give a specific example of a set $S$ that you're interested in, e.g., $S=\{17,3,99\}$? Is it accurate to say that your question is *"Given a finite list of integers, not necessarily in order, what is an algorithm for putting them in order?"*

Comment: Not enough information.  What is $<$, as you don't really say what kind of elements $S$ has?

Comment: The elements in the set are integers.

Comment: Are you asking about sorting algorithms?

Comment: Are you looking for something like"We index the elements of $S$ in ascending order." or is this question about something else?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by algorithms. If it is formulated mathematically then sure.

Comment: We can take the example above where $S=\{17,3,99\}$. Is there a way to construct $a=(a_1,a_2,a_3)=(3,17,99)$ based on $S$? To be honest, the ordering doesn't matter, it can be descending as well. I thought it would somehow be easier to assume an ascending order.

Comment: When you say "make" or "construct" what do you mean? A proof of existence? A formula? An algorithm? Or what? If this is a question about programming, then you need to say something about the representation of the data. If it is a question about mathematical notation for use in a proof, then why do you need to say more than "let $a_1, a_2, \dots, a_n$ be the $n$ elements of $S$ listed in increasing order"?

Comment: I apologize for the ambiguity in the question. At first my thought was to have some type of function $f:S\to \{(a_1,\ldots,a_n) : a_1<\cdots < a_n\}$ represent the ordering. Explaining it with text works too, but I prefer to learn the art of mathematically formulating these types of things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking at the comments, it seems to me that you're asking about **sorting algorithms** ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm)), which are certainly a part of mathematics, in the area of theoretical computer science (there's [a separate Stack Exchange site for it](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com) though; [here's the list of questions on sorting](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sorting)).

Sorting algorithms are usually discussed in terms of asymptotic analysis (as the size of the list of things to be sorted grows, how does the amount of time it takes to sort grow), their efficiency in some aspect (e.g. if comparing two elements of the set will take a long time, you may want to choose an algorithm that makes few comparisons), or their suitability given assumptions about the data (e.g., whether the data will already be "mostly" sorted).

For a simple example of a sorting algorithm, look at **selection sort** ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort)): given the set $S$,

- Let $a_1=\min(S)$
- Let $a_2 = \min(S\setminus\{a_1\})$
- Let $a_3 = \min(S\setminus\{a_1,a_2\})$
- ...

Comment: This is a really nice way to formulate it, thanks. One question though: Is there a way to represent it as maybe some kind of sorting function or mapping $f:S→\{(a_1,…,a_n):a_1<⋯<a_n\}$?